# AsyncTask doesn't do onProgressUpdate Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Seems like this class is not working because it never publishes progress.
`onPostExecute` actually works. But this class relies mostly on `progressUpdate`.

```
class DoBackgroundStuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... a) {

        String rawContactsDl;
        while(true) {

            if (isFinished == true) {
                backgroundStopped = true;
                break;
            }

            //DO SOME STUFF
            publishProgress(1);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "done";
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(int progress) {
        Log.i("VERBOSE","onProgress " + progress);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("VERBOSE","onPosts " + result);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh The Man! Infinite loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your onProgressUpdate should look like that:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate (Integer... values)
```

always use @Override to catch such mistakes

Answer (score 5):

The `onProgressUpdate()` signature is wrong. It should be

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
```

Comment: Hello.. Can you see my question.